# Not all list items are lining up correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to understand why every "row" after my first row of list items is not following the same margin rule as the first "row.

What I would prefer is that all rows here follow the same margins as the second rule. I've wrapped everything in a div so that I can center my div element to make my wrapped list centered on my webpage.

Thanks in advance!

```css
:root {
background-color: skyblue;
}

.list {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 8%;
}

.box {
  width: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20%;
  margin: 1%;
  border-radius: 4.5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
  href="/Users/skyler/Documents/GitHub/Code/the_color_wheeling_boxes.css"/>

<div class="back">
  <ul class="list">
<!-- box 1-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 2-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 3-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 4-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 5-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 6-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 7-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 8-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 9-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 10-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 11-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 12-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 13-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 14-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 15-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 16-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 17-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 18-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 19-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>
<!-- box 20-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></div></li>

  </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have there additional `</div>` in each `LI`. Remove it.

In the first row you close the parent `div`, other LIs are outside `.back`, outside `.back ul`.

Your code is interpreted like

```
<div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="row">...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<li class="row">...</li>
<li class="row">...</li>
<li class="row">...</li>
```

Working code to question.

```css
:root {
background-color: skyblue;
}

.list {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 8%;
}

.box {
  width: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20%;
  margin: 1%;
  border-radius: 4.5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
  href="/Users/skyler/Documents/GitHub/Code/the_color_wheeling_boxes.css"/>

<div class="back">
  <ul class="list">
<!-- box 1-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 2-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 3-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 4-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 5-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 6-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 7-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 8-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 9-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 10-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 11-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 12-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 13-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 14-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 15-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 16-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 17-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 18-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 19-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>
<!-- box 20-->    <li class="box"> <input type="checkbox" class="check"></li>

  </ul>
</div>
</html>
```